# How can I make this delete query being run on postgres faster?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

There are two schema in the same database - oatarchival and oat
The schemas are completely similar to each other.

Here is the query that I am running, which is taking lot of time

```
DELETE FROM oat.oat_user_tag_verification  
  using oatarchival.oat_user_tag_verification outv, oat.fp_archived f  
  WHERE outv.tag_id = f.tag_id and f.is_archived=false  
  and oat_user_tag_verification.user_id = outv.user_id and   
    oat_user_tag_verification.tag_id = outv.tag_id and   
    oat_user_tag_verification.verification_status = outv.verification_status  
    and oat_user_tag_verification.created_at=outv.created_at   
    and oat_user_tag_verification.updated_at=outv.updated_at
```

Here is the explain verbose out of this query -

```
"Delete on oat.oat_user_tag_verification  (cost=14989031.30..16227081.67 rows=1 width=18)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=14989031.30..16227081.67 rows=1 width=18)"
"        Output: oat_user_tag_verification.ctid, outv.ctid, f.ctid"
"        Join Filter: (outv.tag_id = f.tag_id)"
"        ->  Merge Join  (cost=14989031.30..16021422.32 rows=1 width=28)"
"              Output: oat_user_tag_verification.ctid, oat_user_tag_verification.tag_id, outv.ctid, outv.tag_id"
"              Merge Cond: ((oat_user_tag_verification.tag_id = outv.tag_id) AND (oat_user_tag_verification.user_id = outv.user_id) AND (oat_user_tag_verification.verification_status = outv.verification_status) AND (oat_user_tag_verification.created_at = ou (...)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=13223314.06..13368102.38 rows=57915328 width=38)"
"                    Output: oat_user_tag_verification.ctid, oat_user_tag_verification.user_id, oat_user_tag_verification.tag_id, oat_user_tag_verification.verification_status, oat_user_tag_verification.created_at, oat_user_tag_verification.updated_at"
"                    Sort Key: oat_user_tag_verification.tag_id, oat_user_tag_verification.user_id, oat_user_tag_verification.verification_status, oat_user_tag_verification.created_at, oat_user_tag_verification.updated_at"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on oat.oat_user_tag_verification  (cost=0.00..1005001.28 rows=57915328 width=38)"
"                          Output: oat_user_tag_verification.ctid, oat_user_tag_verification.user_id, oat_user_tag_verification.tag_id, oat_user_tag_verification.verification_status, oat_user_tag_verification.created_at, oat_user_tag_verification.updated_at"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=1765717.25..1812477.56 rows=9352062 width=38)"
"                    Output: outv.ctid, outv.tag_id, outv.user_id, outv.verification_status, outv.created_at, outv.updated_at"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=1765717.25..1789097.40 rows=9352062 width=38)"
"                          Output: outv.ctid, outv.tag_id, outv.user_id, outv.verification_status, outv.created_at, outv.updated_at"
"                          Sort Key: outv.tag_id, outv.user_id, outv.verification_status, outv.created_at, outv.updated_at"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on oatarchival.oat_user_tag_verification outv  (cost=0.00..171454.62 rows=9352062 width=38)"
"                                Output: outv.ctid, outv.tag_id, outv.user_id, outv.verification_status, outv.created_at, outv.updated_at"
"        ->  Seq Scan on oat.fp_archived f  (cost=0.00..191863.83 rows=1103642 width=14)"
"              Output: f.ctid, f.tag_id"
"              Filter: (NOT f.is_archived)"
```

Here is the create table structure of all tables involved:

Table fp_archived:

```
CREATE TABLE fp_archived
(
  tag_id bigint NOT NULL,
  detection_url text,
  image_id bigint NOT NULL,
  pixel_x smallint NOT NULL,
  camera_num smallint NOT NULL,
  pixel_y smallint NOT NULL,
  width smallint NOT NULL,
  height smallint NOT NULL,
  is_archived boolean DEFAULT false,
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('fp_archived_seq'::regclass),
  drive_id character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT fp_archived_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Table oat_user_tag_verification:

```
CREATE TABLE oatarchival.oat_user_tag_verification
(
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  tag_id bigint NOT NULL,
  verification_status integer NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT oat_user_tag_verification_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id, tag_id, verification_status, created_at),
  CONSTRAINT oat_user_tag_verification_tag_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
      REFERENCES oatarchival.oat_tags (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT oat_user_tag_verification_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES oatarchival.oat_users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT oat_user_tag_verification_verification_status_fkey FOREIGN KEY (verification_status)
      REFERENCES oatarchival.oat_tag_verification_status (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

The delete query runs for hours and hours. How can I optimize it?
What indexes should I be created for this query to become faster?

Comment: You should `CREATE INDEX` for the field involve

Comment: Can you guide which index should I create?

Comment: sorry wrong link. check here for some tips MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: This is postgres, does that matter though?

Comment: not really, tips are the same

Comment: Should the order of fields in where clause be same as that in index?

Comment: Should I be putting an index on tag_id and is_archived columns of fp_Archived table?

Comment: What about oat_user_tag_verification?

Comment: The performance tunning require lot of testing. 1) create index 2) check explain plan 3) look for `FULL SCAN`  4) try to add another index for avoid that scan 5) repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `EXPLAIN` output (unfortunately you didn't run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`) I'd suggest the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON oatarchival.oat_user_tag_verification(
   ctid,
   tag_id,
   user_id,
   verification_status,
   created_at,
   updated_at
);

CREATE INDEX ON oat.oat_user_tag_verification(
   tag_id,
   user_id,
   verification_status,
   created_at,
   updated_at
);
```

These can help with the merge join.

Then I'd create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON oat.fp_archived(tag_id);
```

This will speed up the nested loop join.

Not sure if that is the best way to run the query, but it's a starting point.

Comment: Please help me figure what can I improve about this question to help lift my question ban?

Comment: What do you mean by "question ban"?

Comment: Banned from asking questions on stackoverflow :(

Comment: No idea - maybe you should [ask Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Answer (score 1):

One hint out of bad experience - try to fiddle with work_mem setting for the session. I had similar problem with incredible costs of queries on new PostgreSQL 9.6 and fount that it simply needs higher limit of work_mem.